# Codename one ActionListener build process not working

Tags: eclipse, build, ide, codenameone

I am building my first app with **codename one**.
However I think that there is a bug during build when using eclipse and the new GUI Builder.
I'm on eclipse neon and just installed the cn1 plugin this week.

1) The main thing which causes actionListeners not to work is that there is a line missing inside the EventCallbackClass

```
public void actionPerformed(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {
            com.codename1.ui.Component sourceComponent = ev.getComponent();
            if(sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent() != null) {
                sourceComponent = sourceComponent.getParent().getLeadParent();
            }

            if(sourceComponent == gui_createAccount) {
             --------------missing------------------
            }
}
```

The **oncreateAccountActionEvent**-method should be invoked in there, but it is not in the generated code.

It probaly is caused because I get an error during build

2) I get this error when clicking the "Action Event" within the "Property Sheet" -> "Events" view.

```
'Building workspace' has encountered a problem. Errors occured during the build.

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'MA'.
Ant build C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\build.xml already in progress. Concurrent Ant builds are possible if you specify to build in a separate JRE.
Ant build C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\build.xml already in progress. Concurrent Ant builds are possible if you specify to build in a separate JRE.
```

The console window however looks fine to me

```
  [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
  [echo]            code size and wider device support
  [javac] C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\build.xml:147: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
  [javac] C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\build.xml:171: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
Buildfile: C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\build.xml

jar:
  [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\build\tmp
  [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\build\tmp
  [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\sieben\workspace\MA\dist\MA.jar
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Thanks for any advice, maybe I have to start over...

**Edit - workaround:**

specify the action event listener method inside the constructor like this:

```
 gui_createAccount.addActionListener((ev) -> {
             oncreateAccountActionEvent(ev);
        });
```

Comment: I added a workaround to keep the code working until the fix is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was already fixed in the other IDE's but seems to still impact Eclipse. We'll try to release an Eclipse update as soon as the responsible engineer can muster it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Until then I will overwrite it in the constructor.